# Safari 7 background-image disappears

Tags: html, css, safari

I have a website which is working fine in all browsers except **Safari 7**
For some reasons the background-image disappears randomly when the site is loaded.. When you scroll down sometimes they re-appear. I've never seen anything like this.

> The site is here http://fourseasonsrally.com/2/public

Any Mac user with 5minutes of spare time? 
Thank you!

### Browserstack

I'm trying to reproduce the issue ( I don't own a mac ), but browserstack is way to slow for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

### The problem was caused by a CSS3 Animation

I was using **animate.css** to fadeInDown the different columns.

```
<div class="col-md-4 animated fadeInDown">
```

Removing these animations fixed the problem. No idea know what is causing this behaviour.
I will look further into it